# R Import text file as list of dataframes

Tags: r, text, import

I have a long txt file organized as follows:

```
RANGE
P1 H1
P3 H4
P10 H72
P14 H76
;
RANGE
P1 H1
P10 H8
P11 H8
;
...
```

I would like to read it in R creating a list of dataframes, where RANGE and ; delimit the content of each one. Therefore, each dataframe should have two columns (P's and H's) and different number of rows. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Absolutely in `R` or are you open to other tools ?

Comment: Only R. I need the list as input for further analyses and the solution posted works perfectly fine. Thanks anyway for asking.

Comment: I just meant there's tools aimed at text manipuation (like `awk` which can turn this file into something easiest to load into R after, avoiding parsing the lines twice, once for reading and once for creating a list). but if the answer works for you that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using `read.table` after reading it with `readLines` and `split`ting the elements based on the position of 'RANGE'

```
lst <- lapply(split(lines, cumsum(lines=="RANGE")), 
    function(x) read.table(text=x[-c(1, length(x))], header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
lst
#$`1`
#   V1  V2
#1  P1  H1
#2  P3  H4
#3 P10 H72
#4 P14 H76

#$`2`
#   V1 V2
#1  P1 H1
#2 P10 H8
#3 P11 H8
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
```