# have a folder of .csv files, would like to combine them into one dataframe in R and use each filename as a column header

Tags: r, csv

This may be a lot to ask in a single post but bear with me haha.

I have a folder full of files, each with a unique name but the same structure (for example: "C1T1_A_tran1.csv" and "C1T2_B_tran2.csv").

There are a few things I would like to do with these files in R:

1. How do I take each file name and turn it into a column header? (so "C1T1_A_tran1.csv" would be column header "C1T1_A_tran1")
2. How do I take a single column from the original file, and put it under the corresponding column? (So for example I would like to take column 14 from the original file of "C1T1_A_tran1.csv" and place those values in the "C1T1_A_tran1" column of the new dataframe)
3. How can I ensure that the columns all align in a way that they all end in the same row (so several columns will have NAs for their first few rows before their values appear in the column)?
   -- example :

```
C1T1_A  C1T1_B
    32      NA
    33      NA
    12      02
    04      22
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Import text file as list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464291/r-import-text-file-as-list-of-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

1. You could use `list.files()` to list the files in a directory.  Let's say that your files are in a directory called "datafiles", you could then do:

```
names <- list.files("datafiles/", pattern="csv$")
```

The above finds all files that end with "csv".

2. Actually, the third question probably comes next - how do you delete the first missing values.  You could do this by finding the first non-missing value and deleting the ones before that. Let's say you want to take the 14th column of the dataset, you could do:

```
library(rio)
library(tibble)
## read in the data
dat <- import(paste0("datafiles/", names[1]))
## take the 14th column and call it x
x <- dat[,14]
## find the first non-missing value
start.ind <- which.min(!is.na(x))
## Keep only those after (and including) start.ind
x <- x[start.ind:length(x)]
## make variable names by removing .csv from file names
vnames <- gsub("\\.csv", "", names)
## make the first data frame
out <- tibble(x=x)
## rename the variable in the output dataset
names(out) <- vnames[1]
```

3. Loop over all of the names and append the data.  This requires that starting with the first non-missing value will result in vectors of the same length always.  If that's not true, this won't work.

```
for(i in 2:length(names)){
  dat <- import(paste0("datafiles/", names[i]))
  x <- dat[,14]
  start.ind <- which.min(!is.na(x))
  x <- x[start.ind:length(x)]
  out[[vnames[i]]] <- x
}
```

That should make a dataframe that has all of the right properties.  I don't have your files, so I can't confirm, but this should be a good start.